# Password not saved into database bcrypt nodejs

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I'm trying to make an login/signup system with authentication. Im using Nodejs with bcrypt to encrypt the data.

My problem is that the hashed pw does not get stored into the DB.

Here is my signup route,

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        error: err,
      });
    } else {
      const user = new User({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hash,
      });
      user
        .save()
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
          res.status(201).json({
            message: 'User created',
          });
        })

        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).json({
            error: err,
          });
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Schema file

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    match: /(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/,
    password: { type: String, required: true },
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

User model

```
const user = new User({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hash,
      });
```

I think the problem has something with how it runs asynch. I manage to console log the hash. What could I try to debug this problem for myself? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Show what you have in DB after save (using Kompass for instance)

Comment: The password field is empty, only _id and email is filled in.

Comment: So console.log(hash) before `const user` shows the hash? Can you add user schema and model definitions?

Comment: Yes, added files to OP

Comment: As an aside, you should have a `NOT NULL` constraint on your password column, if it is truly required. This would have prevented you from writing incorrect data into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You included `password` definition as a field of `email` definition.
It should be like this:

```js
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    match: /(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/,
  },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});
```